# JQuery - Confirm that password contains non alphanumeric character

Tags: jquery, alphanumeric

I wanna check that a password contains a non alphanumeric character (like !).

Is there any similar solution for this as this is for alphabetic characters:
I want a true if the password contains a non-alphanumeric character.

```
var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');

if($("#input-set-password").val().match(upperCase))
{
}
```

Comment: Compulsory xkcd: [Password Strength](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: So you want to force your users to create password they might not remember, thus writing it down on post-it notes, saved in email or similar?

It is a good approach to encourage the use of non alphanumeric character. I don't think it is clever to enforce it.

Comment: xkcd: Password Strength
and that answear makes 100% sense, I will reconsider. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it. the `result` variable will be true if it's only alphanumeric and false if it contains non-alphanumeric characters

```
var reg_password1 = 'test123';
var letters = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
var result = letters.test(reg_password1);
```

To check if it contains at least 1 number and lower case and uppercase letter:

```
if(/\d/.test(reg_password1) && /[a-z]/.test(reg_password1) && /[A-Z]/.test(reg_password1))
```

To combine those:

```
var reg_password1 = 'test123';
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(reg_password1) && /\d/.test(reg_password1) && /[a-z]/.test(reg_password1) && /[A-Z]/.test(reg_password1))
{
    //Has at least 1 uppercase 1 lowercase 1 number and is only alphanumeric
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/unowsr4r/1/)

Comment: I see. Hmm, but I wanna check so that the password at least contains one uppcase character, one numeric and one non alphanumeric (!).

Comment: I'm looking for something that works with !¤% etc. So non-alphanumerics.
I wanna have a string like "Asd1!" return true.

Comment: this functions does what you want, it just returns false instead of true

Comment: It return false for "Asd1!" yes, but it returns false for "asd" too.

Comment: Because asd doesn't have an uppercase and a number in it which is what you asked for. you wanted it to check if it has at least 1 number 1 lowercase and 1 uppercase character

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear and thank you for the help.
I want to check if the text has at least 1 uppcase, 1 number and 1 non-number or non-alphabetic like !. The last one is the one I'm stuck on.

Answer (score 1):

I used jquery.validate.js.
You don't have to mess with js checking if the input has the right characters, simply mark it up on html and it does the rest for you. E.g

```
<input data-val="true" <!-- Tell validate to check this input --> data-val-length="The Password must be at least  6 characters long." <!-- Message shown when length isn't meet --> data-val-length-max="100" <!-- Max length for 'this' input --> data-val-length-min="6" <!-- Minimum length for 'this' input--> data-val-required="The Password field is required." <!-- Error message shown if input is empty---> id="Password" name="Password" type="text" value="">
```

More on https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score -1):

There were two things wrong here:

1) Your expression checked whether one uppercase character was present anywhere in a string. Wheras my edited expression `^[A-Z]+$` "translates" to:

"A string that has uppercase letters (`+` = at least one, or more)  from its start (`^`) till its end (`$`)."

2) `match()` will - as the name implies - find and return all matches. You'll want to use `test()` on the regex here instead, which will return either true or false, as you can see:

```js
var upperCase= new RegExp('^[A-Z]+$');
console.log(upperCase.test($("#input-set-password").val()));
console.log(upperCase.test($("#input-set-password2").val()));
console.log(upperCase.test($("#input-set-password3").val()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input-set-password" value="ANBASFJH" />
<input type="text" id="input-set-password2" value="ANBASFJHasg" />
<input type="text" id="input-set-password3" value="ANBASF123" />
```